# AngularJS: Passing Variable from Controller to Directive to be Interpolated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a controller's variable into a directive so it can be placed in the directive's template.

I have a directive like so:

```
app.directive('alert', function() {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: "partials/templates/alert.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.type = attrs.type;
    }
};
});
```

with a template like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-{{type}}">
    <strong ng-if="type">{{type | capitalize}}:</strong> <span ng-transclude></span>
</div>
```

And I use the directive as follows:

```
 <alert ng-show="alert.message" type="{{alert.type}}">{{alert.message}}</alert>
```

My ctrl has a variable that looks like this:

```
$scope.alert = {
    type: 'success',
    message: 'alert message'
}
```

The problem is that `scope.type` in the directive keeps showing up as the string '{{alert.type}}' in the template, when I want it to show up as simply the string 'success'.

I've tried giving the directive an isolate scope like:

```
scope: {
    type: '@'
}
```

but then the `ng-show="alert.message` in the html fails (won't return true if it exists, so the directive is never displayed) because the directive lost access to the ctrl's scope.

What's the proper way of passing this variable off from the controller to the directive and having it interpolated?

Comment: Do you need the handlebars {{...}} in this case? Try passing `alert.type` without them.

Comment: Tried without and it didn't fix it. My understanding is that directives handle their attrs as strings, unless you assign the directive an isolate scope and the proper values (=, @, or &). So `scope.type = attrs.type` wouldn't run any evaluation (unless you do something with $parse). So you have to evaluate it, in this case with {{...}}, before the directive gets it.

Answer (score 0):

A plunkr or fiddle would have helped. The thing should work without isolated scope too. What i can suggest you would be to move the ng-show outside the directive html tag and for the type attribute use expression without `{{}}`. Something like this

```
<span ng-show="alert.message">
 <alert type="alert.type">{{alert.message}}</alert>
</span>
```

and then use the isolated scope approach.

Comment: You're right, this seemed like something that should work without a problem and I put together a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfPB5/2/ Which works as I initially hoped. For some reason my angularjs project isn't doing the same. Looks like my problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Absolutely no idea why this worked, but on my actual project I'm using `templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html'` as opposed to the `template` above, and when I switched my actual project over to `template` from `templateUrl` it worked. Any idea why this would be the case?